# How do I save xml exactly as is to a xml database field?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

At the moment, if I save `<element></element>` to a SQL Server 2008 database in a field of type xml, it converts it to `<element/>.`

How can I preserve the xml empty text as is when saving?

In case this is a gotcha, I am utilising Linq to Sql as my ORM to communicate to the database in order to save it.

Comment: As far as XML is concerned, those are syntactically the same. Why do you care?

Comment: Esteban, the content will eventually be processed to display on a web page. Unfortunately, browsers do care.

Comment: Looks like there is no way to do that on SQL, I guess you have to hanlde this on your xslt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for is not possible.

SQL Server stores data in `xml` columns as a binary representation, so any extraneous formatting is discarded, as you found out.

To preserve the formatting, you would have to store the content in a text field of type `varchar(MAX)` or `nvarchar(MAX)`. Hopefully you don't have to run XML-based queries on the data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189887.aspx